# How can I find out why my storage space on Amazon EC2 is full?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I run `df -h` on my Amazon EC2 server, this is the output:

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXXX ~]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1             25G   25G     0 100% /
tmpfs                 4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /dev/shm
```

For some reason, something is eating up my storage space.

I am trying to find all of the big files/folders
and this is what I get back:

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXXX ~]$ sudo du -a / | sort -n -r | head -n 10
993580  /
639296  /usr
237284  /usr/share
217908  /usr/lib
206884  /opt
150236  /opt/app
150232  /opt/app/current
150224  /opt/app/current/[deleted].com
113432  /usr/lib64
```

How can I find out what's eating my storage space?

Comment: Don't forget to set up logroate after this incidence.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Well, I think its one (or more) logfiles which have grown too large and need to be removed/backupped. I would suggest going after the big files first. So find all files greater than `10 MB` (10 MB is a big enough file size, you can choose +1M for 1MB similarly)

```
sudo find / -type f -size +10M -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

and now you can identify which ones are causing the trouble and deal with them accordingly.

As for your original `du -a / | sort -n -r | head -n 10` command, that won't work since it is sorting by size, and so, all ancestor directories of a large file will go up the pyramid, while the individual file will most probably be missed.

Note: It should be pretty simple to notice the occurence of similar other log files/binaries in the location of the files you so find, so as a suggestion, do `cd` in to the directory containing the original file to cleanup more files of the same kind. You can also iterate with the command for files with sizes greater than `1MB` next, and so on.

Answer (score 40):

If you are not able to find any gigantic file , killing some processes might solve the issue (it worked for me, read full answer to know why)

**Earlier:**

```
/dev/xvda1       8256952 7837552         0 100% /
```

**Now**

```
/dev/xvda18256952 1062780   6774744  14% /
```

**Reason:**
If you do `rm <filename>` on a file which is currently open by any process, it doesn't delete the file and the process still could be writing to the file. These ghost files can't be found by `find` command and they can't be deleted. Use this command to find out which processes are using deleted files:

```
lsof +L1
```

Kill the processes to release the files. Sometimes its difficult to kill all the processes using the file. Try restarting the system (I don't feel good, but that's a quick solution, makes sure no process uses the deleted file)

Read This:
https://serverfault.com/questions/232525/df-in-linux-not-showing-correct-free-space-after-file-removal/232526

Comment: For some reason, my instance ran out of space today and I rebooted and it went from 100% usage to 24%. Do we know the cause of this? I'd hate for it to happen in production as that would cause a real problem!

Comment: I haven't faced the problem again. I think it was either a memory leak or the server logs (which I was not redirecting to a file)

Comment: Ah in my case it turns out it was a gigantic log file (6gb). Fixed it! Cheers!

Comment: Fixed for me as well, thanks.

Comment: My sql server would not connect even after clearing up some space. Rebooting the instance sorted the problem and cleared up space as well. I was seeing error ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (2) while trying to connect to mysql. Many thanks for the answer

Comment: Oh this is awesome!

Comment: Saviour! Huge log file in ghost state. Thank You!

Answer (score 15):

At `/`, type `du -hs *` as `root`:

```
$ sudo su -
cd /; du -hs *
```

You will see the full size of all folders and identify the bigger ones.

Comment: This one is helpful for troubleshooting.  But sometimes the numbers do not add up when you go into a subdirectory and run the command again.

Answer (score 11):

This space is consumed by mail notifications

you can check it by typing

```
sudo find / -type f -size +1000M -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

It will show large folders above 1000MB

Result will have a folder

```
/var/mail/username
```

You can free that space by running the following command

```
> /var/mail/username
```

Note that greater than (>) symbol is not a prompt, you have to run the cmd with it.

Now check you space free space by

```
df -h
```

Now you have enough free space, Enjoy... :)

Answer (score 2):

ansh0l's answer is the way to go to find large files.  But, if you want to see how much space each directory in your files system is consuming, cd to the root directory, then do `du -k --max-depth=`'.  This will show you how much space is being consumed by each subdirectory within the root directory.  When you spot the culprit, cd to that directory then run the same command again, and repeat, until you find the files that are consuming all of the space.

Comment: While I agree this is a good solution, I don't see much point in having to iterate over and over again. *Usually*, the culprits you are looking for shouldn't be too deep to find, but if they are (and probably otherwise as well), doing a simple `find` and then `cd`ing into the file's directory will be much more effective then iterating manually.

Comment: I've used both methods at various times. Like you said, the culprits usually aren't very deep, so using `du` usually takes only a few iterations.  If the files are small, but there are many of them (e. transactional log records that are written to individual files), then a `find` command that looks for large files won't find them.