# How to delete files matching linux command output

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I have a list of files which I got using `find / -type f -size +10M -exec ls -l {} \;`
I got this command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20032145/5437621)

How can I remove all these files ?

I tried

```
sudo rm `find / -type f -size +10M -exec ls -l {} \;`
```

but it doesn't work.

Also, what does `{} \` do ? And what's the use of `-exec` in this command, will the pipe operator not work ?

Comment: I recommend you [read the `find` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).

Comment: As for your problem, why don't you have `find` execute `rm` for you instead of `ls`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude will that work ?

Comment: `'{}'` is the placeholder for the `exec` command (it works a bit like `xargs`). It is replaced by the file name found for every new file meeting requirements is found. `\;` is used with `-exec` option which denotes the termination of `exec`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I finally got it to work with @some-programmer-dude suggestion:

```
find / -type f -size +10M -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be possible to have `find` run `rm` on each file found, but I couldn't get it to work.

So here is my solution using a for loop:

```
for $f in `find / -type f -size +10M`;do rm $f;done
```

Comment: Outch! `find / -type f -size +10M -exec sudo rm '{}' +`

Comment: @ceving the `+` did the trick for me. When I tried ending the command with `\;` it just kept saying "missing argument to `-exec'