# How to clean up aws ec2 server?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I recently ran a report on my EC2 server and was told that it ran out of space. I deleted the csv that was partially generated from my report (it was going to be a pretty sizable one) and ran `df -h` and was surprised to get this output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  7.0G  718M  91% /
devtmpfs         15G  100K   15G   1% /dev
tmpfs            15G     0   15G   0% /dev/shm
```

I surprised not only by how little was available/how much space was used,(I am on the `/dev/xvda1` instance) but also surprised to see 2 alternative filesystems.

To investigate what was taking so much space, I ran `du -h` in `~` and saw the list of all directories on the server. Their reported size in aggregate should not be even close to 7 gb...which is why I ask "what is taking up all that space??"

The biggest directory by far was the `~` directory containing 165MB all other were 30MB and below. My mental math added it up to WAY less than 7gb. (if I understand du -h correctly, all directories within ~ ought to be included within 165MB...so I am very confused how 7 gb could be full)

Anyone know what's going on here, or how I can clean up the space? Also, just out of curiosity, is there a way to utilize the devtmpfs/tmpfs servers from the same box? I am running on AWS Linux, with versions of python and ruby installed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20032145/7207514), it seems as though it might be because of log files getting too large. Try run the command OP mentioned in their answer, in order to find all large files: `sudo find / -type f -size +10M -exec ls -lh {} \;`

Comment: Used this to discover some old docker files that were multiple gb large.

Answer (score 5):

For me, the best option was to delete the `overlay2` docker folder and to completely refresh docker to a clean state. It clears up more than 3GB in my case.

Important note: it will stop and remove your instances, so you need to rebuild them.

In order to do that, first stop the docker engine

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
```

Prune and then delete the entire `docker` directory (not just the `overlay2` folder):

```
docker system prune
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

Restart docker:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

The engine will restart without any images, containers, volumes, user created networks, or swarm state.

Additionaly you can remove `snap` with:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
```